# Any idea to get mobile identification in php program

Tags: php, mobile, identity

There is a vote module in my program.

Users could voting up /down use PC or moblie phones in login state .and we alse allow users voting in logout state.

So that we have to check users vote only once in logout state. Is there any Idea to do this with php?

And I think we must storage PC's ip/MAC or mobile's identification like phone number etc.

Thanks for u help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of informations that you can find in `$_SERVER` about the current user , for ip addresse it works for both mobile and pc it's not depending on the platform and you can find it in :

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```